# Websphere Portal with Angular 6

Tags: websphere, portal

I want to create one Application using websphere Portlet with Angular 6. Can anyone please help how to proceed with that and is it possible angular 6 with Portlet.

Regards,
Srinivas.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not done this, you should be able to create a script portlet/application where you can use Angular 6.  You may have to do a bit of tinkering with the theme to get newer versions of js libraries if needed, but that should not be a big deal.  Here is a link to resources that will get you started: https://developer.ibm.com/digexp/docs/docs/script-portlet/using-angular-angular-4-single-page-application-script-portlet/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, it's too late for the answer, but it might useful for others.

We are able to integrate with Angular with the portal application.

1) Created new portlet.

2) Create a control class

3) Create Jsp, in jsp we did create an iframe and embedded angular application in an iframe.

Step1) Created a new portlet. in portlet.xml

```
<portlet>
   <portlet-name>newPortletNm</portlet-name>
   <display-name>newPortletNm</display-name>
   <portlet-class>.....</portlet-class>
   <init-param>
      <name>contextConfigLoc>
      <value>WEB-INF/context/porlet/newPortletNm.xml<value>
   <supports>....</supports>
   <supported-locale>....</supported-locale>
      ....
   <resource-bundle>com.myorg.gi.myappnm.NewPortletNmResource</resource-bundle>
   <portlet-info>
       <title>NewPortleTitle>
       <keywords>NewPortel</keywords>
   </portle-info>
</portlet>
```

newPortletNm.xml

```
<beans>
   <bean id="newPortletController" class="com.myorg.gi.myappnm.NewPortletController">
      <property name="session" value="true"/>
       ......
      <protperty name="formView" value="newPorlet"/>
   </bean>
   <!-- Interceptors-->
   <bean id="paraMappingIntercep" class="spring ParameterMappingInterceptor"/>
   <!--Handler mapping -->
   <bean id="porletMapping" class="spring PortletModeHandlerMapping">
      <property name="interceptors">
          <list>
              <ref bean=".....>
           </list>
       </property>
       <property name="portletModeMap">
           <map>
               <entry key="view">
                    <ref bean="newPortletController">
               </entry>
            </map>
       </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

NewPortletNmResource.properties

```
java.portlet.title=My new application title
java.portlet.short-title=New App title
java.portlet.keywords=newPortlet
```

newPortlet.jsp

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>New angular app in portlet</title>
      <meta>
      .....
   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe src="http://localhost:4200/myAngularApp"
   </body>
</html>
```

My angular app loaded in in iframe.